# post php response into div using ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I am currently working on a project. When a user submits a form, it loads a response into a div rather than loading a new page. I have looked at other examples of an ajax form working along with PHP online but it didn't help me solving my problem. (I am rather new to this).

When I click submit, instead of posting the response onto the same page and sending an email to the chosen email address, it takes me to the php file and echo the response there, but does not send any email.

Can anyone see where this is going wrong?

Form code:

```
<form name="contactform" id="contact-form" action="mailer.php">

            <input type="text" class="textbox" name="name" value="Name" required="required" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}">

            <input type="text" class="textbox" name="email" value="Email" required="required" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}">

            <textarea name="message" value="Message:" required="required" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message';}">Message</textarea>

           <input type="submit" value="Send Now">

</form>
                    <div id="response"></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script>
 $("#contactform").submit(function(event) 
 {
     /* stop form from submitting normally */
     event.preventDefault();

     /* get some values from elements on the page: */
     var $form = $( this ),
         $submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' ),
         name_value = $form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val(),
         email_value = $form.find( 'input[name="email"]' ).val(),
         message_value = $form.find( 'textarea[name="message"]' ).val(),
         url = $form.attr('action');

     /* Send the data using post */
     var posting = $.post( url, { 
                       name: name_value, 
                       email: email_value, 
                       message: message_value 
                   });

     posting.done(function( data )
     {
         /* Put the results in a div */
         $( "#response" ).html(data);

     });
});
</script>
```

PHP code: (my php is stored in a seperate file called mailer.php) I am trying to get the PHP $response variable to be posted back and placed into the response div.

```
<?php


    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $to = "your-emailaddresshere@email.com";
    $subject = "New DPS Email from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    $mailed = (mail($to, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers));

    if( isset($_POST['ajax']) )
    $response = ($mailed) ? "1" : "0";
    else
    $response = ($mailed) ? "<h2>Thank You! Your message has been sent.</h2>" : "<h2>Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.</h2>";

    echo $response; 

?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you looked in the broswer's console for errors?

Comment: You have the var url in you $.post. Silly question but I guess elsewhere in your code that is set to the url of your php script

Comment: @Y.Hermes I have tried that and unfortunately it doesn't seem to change the outcome

Comment: @IWebb I'm not sure if it is actually working correctly, but it should be taking the url of the php script from the action variable on the form. I have just realised that hasn't been included in my post, will update it now

Comment: I know this site is about a JQuery plugin but there is a good section on how to debug ajax requests in chrome. https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7 the Diagnosis bit is the interesting bit works for all ajax requests

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm quite new to this so I'm not sure if this is right but on firefox developer console I am getting "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."  that is for the mailer.php file

Comment: Sort your issues into two pieces: post to the form directly and make sure the PHP does what you expect (also read/understand this before putting the site on a public server http://securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection), then fix your JavaScript.  Any time you are trying to sort out both you make your problem harder.

Comment: @acrosman Thanks for the comment. I have got an idea about the security of the form etc, I had just stripped it back to the variables just to see if there was maybe an issue with the sanitize functions messing with the script, but unfortunately now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:
The Form Code

```
<form name="contactform" id="contact-form">
    <!--Your form elements here -->
</form>
```

The javascript code (Use **#contact-form** and not **#contactform**)

```
<script>
$("#contact-form").submit(function(event) 
{
 /* stop form from submitting normally */
 event.preventDefault();

 /* get some values from elements on the page: */
 var $form = $( this ),
     $submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' ),
     name_value = $form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val(),
     email_value = $form.find( 'input[name="email"]' ).val(),
     message_value = $form.find( 'textarea[name="message"]' ).val(),
     url = 'your_url_here';

 /* Send the data using post */
 var posting = $.post( url, { 
                   name: name_value, 
                   email: email_value, 
                   message: message_value 
               });

 posting.done(function( data )
 {
     /* Parse JSON */
     var response = JSON.parse(data);
     $("#response").html(response.msg);

    });
 });
</script>
```

Your PHP Code :

```
<?php


// Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$to = "your-emailaddresshere@email.com";
$subject = "New DPS Email from $name";

// Build the email content.
$email_content = "Name: $name\n";
$email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
$email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

// Build the email headers.
$email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

$mailed = mail($to, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers);

if( $mailed )
$response = json_encode(array("status"=>true,"msg"=>"<h2>Thank You! Your message has been sent.</h2>"));
else
$response = json_encode(array("status"=>false,"msg"=>"<h2>Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.</h2>"));

echo $response; 

?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!
This is laid better than my original code and it encodes and decodes the message then posts it to the array. Only issue I'm still having is, getting the email to actually send. Although I am wondering whether this is due to me using cloud 9 ide

Comment: Welcome @HipHipArray . For the mail issue, you can check that with your hosting provider

Answer (score 2):

correct this and report what happened,

your form ID is "contact-form" and your JQ selector have been set for "contactform".

```
$("#contactform")
```

to

```
$("#contact-form")
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that seems to have been the answer for getting it to post to the div! It's always a typo!
For some reason it still isn't sending the email though :S

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're calling post function, not ajax.

try this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: <your_url>,
   type:'GET',
   data: {'name': name_value, 'email' : email_value, 'message': message_value},
   success: function(data){
        yourdivcontent =  eval(data)
        $( "#response" ).html(yourdivcontent);
   }, 
   error: function(){
        console.log("error");
   }
})
```

In your php function, just encode your response in json

return json_encode(response);

Comment: Thanks for your comment, for whatever reason I am getting an error saying "unexpected token :" 
on this line "data: {'name': name_value, 'email' : email_value, 'message': message_value},"
Also I'm assuming the part where you have put yourdivcontent, this needs to be replaced by the variable which I am passing back from the php mailer script?

Finally, if am I am JSON_encoding, do I need to decode?

Sorry about all the questions, I am just quite new to this and trying to understand what each part is doing

Comment: I forgot to add the 'type' value on the ajax call.. I edited my answer. And yes, you have to put your variable into your div. the data is going to return you an json string

Comment: For some reason it keeps giving me that unexpected token error. Any ideas as to what may be causing that? Thanks in advance

Comment: try to unquote the data line, like this data: {
    name: name_value,
      and so on
}

Answer (score 0):

`echo json_encode($response)` at end of php function

Comment: unfortunately this just echos it on the php page still